# Cannot includ/send jwt token using auth0/angular-jwt

Tags: spring, angular7, angular2-jwt

I use "https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt" to send JWT token to my server, I can see the token when I debug http request (angular) but at the server (java) the token is not found

this is my config jwt

```
JwtModule.forRoot({
  config: {
    headerName: 'API_TOKEN',
    tokenGetter: function tokenGetter() {
      return localStorage.getItem('API_TOKEN');
    },
    whitelistedDomains: ['localhost:8092'],
    // blacklistedRoutes: ['https://localhost:8092/login'],
    authScheme: ''
  }
}),
```

I added a JwtHttpInterceptor for debug my request :

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor() {}
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
 return next.handle(req);
}
}
```

and this is a screenshot : [JWT token in header request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Y4gF.png)

but server could not find this token.

When I try to add token with a chrome pluging, It work and server can find my token : [token added with chrome pluging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBvsz.png)

Can you help me please?

Comment: Can you post all of the Cookie fields (host, HttpOnly, etc.)?

Comment: Hello scottyseus, I don't use Cookies, I store my token into localstorage and after, foreach call to server I get it (my token) from the localstorage and add it to Headers of request, I don't know if it's mandatory to use cookies and local storage? thanks for your help

Comment: @Ahmed Not mandatory but as protection goes, cookies are way safer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution if it will help another person, in fact it comes from the backend, I reversed the spring security filters and my request "OPTIONS" should go through the filter CORS first

```
        httpSecurity
.addFilter(jwtAuthenticationFilter)
.addFilterBefore(corsInputFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class) // OPTIONS REQUEST SHOULD COME HERE IN THE FIRST AND RETURN THE RESPONSE WITHOUT CONTINUE OTHERS FILTERS
.addFilterBefore(tokenAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```